# Join table not working in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, casting

I'm changing my database(sql server) to postgres but the query that I'm used to doesn't work in postgres. the join is not working

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.date,' ',TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.time)
FROM TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS 
JOIN (
SELECT CONCAT(date,' ',MIN(time))::timestamp as mints FROM TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS    
WHERE date = '2017-08-20'
GROUP BY date, date_part('hour', time)      
)tt 
ON TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.time = tt.mints AND TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.date = tt.mints
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

The error is:

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: time without time zone = timestamp without time zone
>   LINE 8:     ON TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.time = tt.mints AND TOTALIZE...
>   ********** Error **********

How can I fix this?

Comment: What result do you expect when comparing a `time` to a `timestamp`? You either need to cast your `time` column to a `timestamp` (but which date?) or your `timestamp` to a `time` value.

Comment: I already changed the data type of time to timestamp and the error is still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the time and date value that you have in different columns (why?) to a single timestamp in order to be able to join on a timestamp column.

Adding a `time` value on a `date` value returns a `timestamp`, so you can use:

```
ON (TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.date + TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.time) = tt.mints
```

---

Unrelated, but:

`concat()` is used to concatenate string values, so you are (implicitly) converting your date & time values to a string. It is usually better to keep the correct data type instead of converting everything to a string:

```
select distinct TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.date + TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.time
```

will preserve return a proper `timestamp` value rather then a `text`

Answer (score 0):

according to your error line , you need explicit cast:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  date || ' ' || FORMAT(to_char(TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.time, 'HH')),
    TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.Ia, TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.Ib, TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.Ic,
    TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.Ineutral, TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.Iang, TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.Ibang,
    TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.Icang, TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.Va, TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.Vb,
    TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.Vc,TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.Vaang, TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.Vbang,
    TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.Vcang,TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.pftotal
    FROM TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS 
    JOIN (
    SELECT CONCAT(date,' ',MIN(time))::timestamp as mints FROM TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS    
    WHERE date = '2017-08-20'
    GROUP BY date, date_part('hour', time)      
)tt 
    ON TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.time = tt.mints AND TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.date = tt.mints
 ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

`concat` returns text...

Comment: ERROR:  operator does not exist: time without time zone = timestamp without time zone
LINE 13:     ON TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.time = tt.mints AND TOTALIZE...
                                              ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: ah - time?.. not timestamp?.. but how you want to compare CONCAT(date,' ',MIN(time)) against time?.. is `'2017-09-14 09:00'` equal `'09:00'`? if so then `'2017-09-13 09:00'` equal `'09:00'`, but then  `'2017-09-14 09:00'` equal `'2017-09-13 09:00'` which is not

Comment: no the result of the first select is all the dates and there time ex. '2017-08-07 12:00' , '2017-08-20 19:00 ' etc. and the second select is '2017-08-20 21:00' and so on. the result must be all the data per hour on the same date

Comment: according to parser `TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.time` is time. with no date - just time - right?..